# Invalid left hand side assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign d_new into d_name , but i keep getting invalid left hand side assignment.

```
 <script> 
var n  = ('${d_name}').length; 
if( n >=14){
   console.log( ('${d_name}') );
   ('${d_new}') =  ('${d_name}').substring(0,14);
}
</script>
```

Comment: That is simply not possible in JavaScript. A string on the left-hand side of `=` makes no sense.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the variable name via a template? `('${d_new}') =  ('${d_name}').substring(0,14);`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This smells like a major [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hi @imvain2 , this is a template file, the variable loaded by ajax. I'm trying to pass shorten the variable name if its more than 14 characters to d_new

Comment: So d_new is a variable that you want to overwrite, but it isn't the same everytime?

Comment: it will be a loop base on my json list. 
eg i have a list of  = Apple, Orange , Milk on my JSON file, i'll pass this to my list and using javascript to load it. but i want to shorten it when its too long.

Comment: @imvain2 yes, thats correct thank you

Comment: I recommend learning JavaScript before using libraries (such as jquery here).

Comment: Could you edit your question and add information on what you try to achieve, what `d_name` and `d_new` are, and how `d_name` is set. Currently your code has neither of these -- there are only string literals.

Comment: Perhaps you want `window[d_new]` (or whatever scope if not global) rather than `('${d_new}')` :-?